# How can I make a for loop in Javascript that will set timeouts from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, settimeout

**Background** (You might want to skip this)

I'm working on a web app that animates the articulation of English phonemes, while playing the sound. It's based on the [Interactive Sagittal Section by Daniel Currie Hall](http://smu-facweb.smu.ca/~s0949176/sammy/), and a first attempt can be found [here](http://thailandian.000webhostapp.com/esol/sammy/index.html).

For the next version, I want each phoneme to have it's own animation timings, which are defined in an array, which in turn, is included in an object variable.

For the sake of simplicity for this post, I have moved the timing array variable from the object into the function.

**Problem**

I set up a for loop that I thought would reference the index i and array t to set the milliseconds for each setTimeout.

```js
function animateSam() {

  var t = [0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000];
  var key = "key_0";

  for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(i);
      key = "key_" + i.toString();
      console.log(key);

      //do stuff here

    }, t[i]);
  }
}

animateSam()
```

However, it seems the milliseconds are set by whatever i happens to be when the function gets to the top of the stack.

**Question:** Is there a reliable way to set the milliseconds from the array?

Comment: Use `let` instead of `var`, or, even better, use array methods instead of `for` loops.

Comment: Did you try to move `i` into another variable inside `for loop body` or more like copy the milliseconds into another variable? Like `var x = t[i]`

Comment: In addition to `let` instead of `var`, why don't you use `i * 1000` instead of the array approach? Seems counterintuitive to hardcode what is easy math..

Comment: why not just set `setTimeout(function() {}, 1000)`?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? The timeouts will be exactly as specified in the array - one second apart. Are you asking why each `alert` shows you `5`?

Comment: @ivan, baao: this is just an example - phonemes do not have one-second-apart timings, his real use case is not that array.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: The `i` value when the function executes will be the i value at the time the function executes. However the `t[i]` when you set the timeout should be correct.

Comment: PS I know it's test code but I hope you know you should never do `key = ...` without assigning it to a var/let/const

Comment: Sorry all - I should have added that each phoneme will have different array lengths as well as different array values, which is why I could not nest the setTimeout functions.

Comment: @Dominic Tobias I had assigned "var key;" outside of the for loop, but forgot to copy it over to my simplified example. Thanks for the heads up, and I've modified the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The for ends before the setTimeout function has finished, so you have to set the timeout inside a closure:

```
function animateSam(phoneme) {

  var t = [0,1000,2000,3000,4000];

  for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    (function(index) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            alert (index);
            key = "key_" + index.toString();
            alert (key);

            //do stuff here

        }, t[index]);
    })(i);
  }
}
```

Here you have the explanation of why is this happening:
https://hackernoon.com/how-to-use-javascript-closures-with-confidence-85cd1f841a6b

Comment: By the way, this is a classic job interview question

Comment: Thanks @A. Llorente - especially for the link to the explanation. I just hate not understanding things even if a problem is solved on the surface :-)

Answer (score 3):

The `for` loop will loop all elements before the first [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) is triggered because of its asynchronous nature. By the time your loop runs, `i` will be equal to `5`. Therefore, you get the same output five times.

You could use a method from the [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) class, for example [`.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

This ensures that the function is enclosed.

```js
[0, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000].forEach((t, i) => {
  setTimeout(function() {

    console.log(i);
    console.log(`key_${i}`);

    //do stuff here

  }, t)
});
```

*Side note:* I would advise you **not** to use `alert` while working/debugging as it is honestly quite confusing and annoying to work with. Best is to use a simple `console.log`.

---

Some more clarifications on the code:

`.forEach` takes in as primary argument the callback function to run on each of element. This callback can itself take two arguments (in our previous code `t` was the current element's value and `i` the current element's index in the array):

```
Array.forEach(function(value, index) {

});
```

But you can use the [arrow function syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), instead of defining the callback with `function(e,i) { ... }` you define it with: `(e,i) => { ... }`. That's all! Then the code will look like:

```
Array.forEach((value,index) => {

});
```

This syntax is a shorter way of defining your callback. There are [some differences though](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/arrow-function-vs-function-declaration-expressions-are-they-equivalent-exch).

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Your code is actually simpler, but I don't quite understand the syntax (it's different to other examples of forEach I have seen), so I went with A. Llorente's answer as it will be easier to apply to my actual code.

Comment: You're right about console.log - alerts were helping to confuse me!

Comment: @Thailandian, it's ok no problem. I made an edit to explain the syntax. I hope it will help you understand better

Comment: Thanks @Ivan. I've already finished modifying my code but it's great that it's there as a reference for others that stumble in here.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a function closure as follows:

```
function animateSam(phoneme) {

  var t = [0,1000,2000,3000,4000];

  var handleAnimation = function (idx) {
    return function() {
      alert(idx);
      key = "key_" + idx.toString();
      alert(key);
      //do stuff here
    };
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    setTimeout(handleAnimation(i), t[i]);
  }
}
```

I this example you wrap the actual function in a wrapper function which captures the variable and passes on the value.